# When creating a new flutter project no android/ios/main.dart folder/file are showing

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I know it has already been asked this, but I have read all the thread opened and tried everything and still when I create a new flutter project there's only the .idea folder and no lib/android/ios folder and main.dart showing.
I have already installed flutter/dart plugins, SDK path is set correctly, path in module (project settings) is set too.
Also flutter doctor -v is not showing any issue. Could anyone help me please? I don't know what to do.

I am usind Android Studio Eels.

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you check in `File Manager(Finder)` of system. and if there are other files exist, then close IDE(`Android Studio`), remove `.idea` folder and open the project again.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're using the wrong way:

Android Studio menu is a little bit confusing. In order to create an empty new Flutter project,
After selecting `File > New > New Flutter Project`:

1. Select **"Flutter"**(not "New Project") on the left
2. Click **"Next"** and follow the wizard.